# SoundCloud iframe embed code does not work on mobile Opera and Chrome in iOS

Tags: ios, google-chrome, iframe, opera, soundcloud

SoundCloud iframe embed code does not work on mobile Opera and Chrome in iOS.

When you embed it, it shows the content of the iframe, but does not play it. It noteworthy to mention that it fully works on Safari in iOS and any browser on desktop.

Thanks for any help.